# Uncaught TypeError: *_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, webpack-4

i have this problem with my Webpack project when i import a class in two different scripts that aren't related, can someone tell me what is wrong? My webpack version is 4.0.0.

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    index: './src/js/index.js',
    firebaseController: './src/js/firebaseController.js',
    login: './src/js/login.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].comp.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 8080,
    publicPath: '/assets/'
  }
}
```

This is the first script where i import the class that ocasionates this error, which is index.js:

```
    import '../sass/main.scss';
    
    import SignIn from './auth/signIn.js';
    import { validatePw, setLoadingPage } from './general/generalFunc.js';
    
    const signInObj = new SignIn();
    
    const formAuth = document.querySelector('.auth__form');
    
    const authEmail = document.querySelector('.auth__input--email');
    const authPw = document.querySelector('.auth__input--pw');
    const authName = document.querySelector('.auth__input--name');
    const authError = document.querySelector('.auth__err');
    
    const inputEye = document.querySelector('.input__eye');
    
    const googleAuth = document.querySelector('.auth__social-item--google');
    const facebookAuth = document.querySelector('.auth__social-item--fb');
    const githubAuth = document.querySelector('.auth__social-item--github');
    
    let eventHandlerEye = false; /* NO USE FOR OTHER EVENTS */
    
    formAuth.addEventListener('submit', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      
      const authEmailVal = authEmail.value;
      const authPwVal = authPw.value;
      const authNameVal = authName.value;
      
      if(validatePw(authPwVal) && authNameVal.trim().length > 5) {
        signInObj.createAccount(authEmailVal, authPwVal, authNameVal);
        putErrorInForm('');
        setLoadingPage();
      } else {
        putErrorInForm('*The password/name is not valid. (Needs more secure password)');
      }
    })
    
    export const putErrorInForm = errorVal => {
      authError.innerHTML = errorVal;
    }
...
```

And this is the second script that is login.js:

```
import '../sass/main.scss';

import SignIn from './auth/signIn.js';

const signInObj = new SignIn();

const formAuth = document.querySelector('.auth__form');

const authEmail = document.querySelector('.auth__input--email');
const authPw = document.querySelector('.auth__input--pw');

const inputEye = document.querySelector('.input__eye');

let eventHandlerEye = false; /* NO USE FOR OTHER EVENTS */


formAuth.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const authEmailVal = authEmail.value;
  const authPwVal = authPw.value;
  
  
})

export const putErrorInForm = errorVal => {
  authError.innerHTML = errorVal;
}

...
```

This is the class that i am importing inside the signIn.js script:

```
import { actualUrl } from '../actualUrl.js';
import { putErrorInForm } from '../index.js';
import { removeLoadingPage } from '../general/generalFunc.js';

export default class SignIn {
  constructor() {}
  
  createAccount(email, password, nameUser) {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(resUser => {
        resUser.user.updateProfile({
          displayName: nameUser
        }).then(() => {
          const configSendVerificationEmail = {
            url: `${actualUrl}/dashboard.html`
          }
          
          resUser.user.sendEmailVerification(configSendVerificationEmail)
          .catch(err => {
            putErrorInForm(err.message);
          });
          
          putErrorInForm('*Last step! Check your email and see the email that we send you to verify your email.');
          removeLoadingPage();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          putErrorInForm(err.message);
        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        putErrorInForm(err.message);
      });
  }
}
```

Whenever i delete one of the two imports in my two scripts the error disappears, i dont know what's happening and what's the problem... Thanks btw